# Google Analytics Access with C#

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I know that there is no official API for Google Analytics but is there a way to access Google Analytics Reports with C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**: Google launched a Google Analytics API today.
[Google Analytics Blog - API Launched](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/04/attention-developers-google-analytics.html)

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a small project that lets you generate pretty much any Analytics report. It's listed on Google's Analytics API page - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataArticlesCode.html

You can read about it here and get the source code - http://www.reimers.dk/blogs/jacob_reimers_weblog/archive/2009/05/09/added-google-analytics-reader-for-net.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I emailed them asking this same question a while back and here's the response I got:

Hello,

Thank you for your email. I apologize for the delay in replying to your email. Google Analytics does not currently provide an API to access the reporting data. However, we do offer export functionality for single reports in the following formats:

- PDF
- Tab separated value (TSV)
- XML
- Excel (CSV)

This feature allows you to easily import report data into your favorite spreadsheet application or to process the data otherwise.

Additionally, we're unable to provide support for custom implementations of Google Analytics. For this level of support, you can contact one of our highly qualified Google Analytics Authorized Consultants for assistance with advanced needs. These partners deliver a number of professional services such as installation support, training, and advanced filter and e-commerce configurations.

For a complete list of our worldwide partners and a more detailed description of the services they offer, please go to http://www.google.com/analytics/support_partner_provided.html

For additional questions, please visit the Analytics Help Center at http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/?utm_id=tf. You can also find helpful tips and information by visiting the Google Analytics Help Forum at http://groups.google.com/group/analytics-help?utm_id=tr.

Sincerely,

[snip]

Analytics Support

---

For the latest updates as well as some helpful tips on Google Analytics, check out the Google Analytics blog at http://analytics.blogspot.com

---

Answer (score 2):

I have a completed library for called GoogleAnalytics.Net that allows you to fire page views/events/transactions from within .net code.

You can download the library from it's project home page:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/projects/details/ga-dot-net

Comment: Looks promising :). Checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

[This guy](http://www.mojoportal.com/mojoportal-gets-advanced-google-analytics-integration.aspx) has had some success with at least some light Analytics integration.  Now I realize this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but he does mention a book and perhaps you can get in touch with him.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **SilverLight Google Analytics Snippet** - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/silverlightTrackingIntro.html

http://msaf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Google%20Analytics

Because Silverlight is C#.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics API changed recently(2012) and because of that most of the codings are changed. so below link will be helpful for c# developers

[Google Analytics API in C# -Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527610/execution-of-request-failed-https-www-google-com-analytics-feeds-accounts-def)

Answer (score 1):

Google has created there own client lib [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/)  which allows for access to most of the Google Apis using dotnet.

Then can be found on [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Google.Apis)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another analytics API for C#
https://github.com/igooana/igooana

This project is aimed at C# 5 and uses `async/await` and `dynamic` extensively. 
I tried to make this API as simple as possible and maximum type-safe.